# Gronwall's inequality and negative functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(r,u,c) \in (\mathbb{R}_+)^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $r \leq u.$ Let $f$ be a bounded and **measurable function** such that $$\forall x \in [r,u],f(x) \leq c \int_r^x f(y)d\lambda_1 (y).$$

Prove that for all $x \in [r,u],f(x) \leq 0.$

Since we are considering a measurable function (not continuous), I do not think the usual proof of Gronwall's inequality could work.

What can we do in this case to prove that $f(x) \leq 0$ ?

Comment: You mean integral from $r$ to $x$, right? If so, I think that you can show that $f(x) \leq \frac{Mc^n(r-x)^n}{n!}$ for all $n \geq 0$ if $M$ is an upper bound on $f$.

Comment: Oops, you’re right, sorry. That’s exactly that.